# How To Remove Default Padding From Bootstrap Nav Bar

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

*Bootstrap* JS/CSS is appending transparent space to the bottom of a `NavBar` inside a `<td>` in my home page. **[This](http://jsfiddle.net/jmJWr/23/) shows a live preview** of the issue I'm having with the default *bootstrap* configuration of `NavBars`.

Here is a complete, (minus the inclusion of the *bootstrap* files) and minimal example of the code I wrote to create the `NavBar`.

```
<html>
<body>
<table align="center" border="1px"><tr>
<td>
<!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse"
                    data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Home</a>
        </div>
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li>
                    <a href="about.html">About Us</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a>
                </li>
                <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                </form>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
</nav>
</td></tr>
</table>
</html>
```

Any help is appreciated.
Cheers.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can update the css class "`navbar`" with updated margin.

```
.navbar { margin-bottom: 0 }
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kiranvarthi/jmJWr/24/

Comment: That was insanely fast. SO FAST I can't even mark the question answered yet. ;)

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest solution for this is, when you export your boostrap version from [here](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#navbar), just edit the `@navbar-margin-bottom` field, you should set it to 0px insted of `@line-height-computed` (default value).